# Why '&' is breaking Django CharField(python strings) into parts?

Tags: django-views

```
I have a function in views.py

    def get_interview_type(request):
        i = None
        title = request.GET['title'] #Here the title becomes different
        try:
            i = Interview.objects.get(title=title) #it looks for that dropdown value
            #Error according to pdb
            #-> i = Interview.objects.get(title=title)
            #    (Pdb) 
            #    DoesNotExist: DoesNotE...exist.',)

            if i.interview_type == "Time Series":
                visit_ids = i.visit_set.all()
                reference_visit_list = [] 
                for visit in visit_ids:
                    reference_visit_list.append(visit.reference_visit)
                reference_visit_list.extend(visit_ids)
                list(set(reference_visit_list))
                len_visits=filter(None,reference_visit_list)
                total_visits = len(len_visits)
                return render_to_response('export/get_details.html',
                                      {'visits':visit_ids,'count':visit_ids.count(),
                                       'total_visits':total_visits},
                                       context_instance=RequestContext(request)
                                      )
            else:
                return render_to_response('export/get_interview_type.html',
                                      {'visits':i.visit_set.all()},
                                       context_instance=RequestContext(request)
                                    )
        except Interview.DoesNotExist:
            pass
```

When the user selects a title from the dropdown this function is called and does it tasks.
Now i have entered a string which include '&' ampersand thinking that it can play a role of 'and' in normal english like this :-

'CI-2-UGI & Bowel Symptom Screening & Characterization'(It is one of that dropdown value)
Now when user selects this value from dropdown the title does not remain the same, instead the title changes to  CI-2-UGI(in title = request.GET['title']) and  before the function executes i recieve a 500 error page.
This is what the error prints in runserver mode

> /home/user/cpms/careprep/tags/4.0/careprep/export/views.py(66)get_interview_type()->None
>   -> pass
>   (Pdb) c
>   [11/Mar/2012 22:05:20] "GET /export/get_interview_type/?title=CI-2-UGI%20&%20Bowel%20Symptom%20Screening%20&%20Characterization HTTP/1.1" 500 64490

Also when i remove that '&'ampersand from the title there is no 500 page.
Why this & causing the problem ? I think in this way every special symbol will cause the same problem .I will appreciate if anybody can guide me on this and how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `&` is used to separate fields in the query string. URL-encode it first.

Comment: I tried this:print urllib.quote(title.encode('utf-8')) and this print urllib.quote_plus(title).In both cases i removed '&' but not actual it still not taking complete title.

Answer (score 0):

```
I studied about URL-encode what Ignacio suggest but i found a clean and better solution.
Instead of comparing with title i used 'id' <option value="">  which is the primary key(id) for
Interview Table and modified the code like this:

def get_interview_type(request):
    i = None
    id = request.GET['id']
    try:
        i = Interview.objects.get(id=id)
        if i.interview_type == "Time Series":
            visit_ids = i.visit_set.all()
            reference_visit_list = [] 
            for visit in visit_ids:
                reference_visit_list.append(visit.reference_visit)
            reference_visit_list.extend(visit_ids)
            list(set(reference_visit_list))
            len_visits=filter(None,reference_visit_list)
            total_visits = len(len_visits)
            return render_to_response('export/get_details.html',
                                  {'visits':visit_ids,'count':visit_ids.count(),
                                   'total_visits':total_visits},
                                   context_instance=RequestContext(request)
                                  )
        else:
            return render_to_response('export/get_interview_type.html',
                                  {'visits':i.visit_set.all()},
                                   context_instance=RequestContext(request)
                                )
    except InterviewTitle.DoesNotExist:
        pass


and for picking the id i use jquery:-
$(function(){   
    $("#id_title").bind("change",function(){
        id = $(this).find("option[value="+ $(this).val()+"]").val();
        url = "../get_interview_type/?id="+id;
        $.get(url, "", function (d){
            $("#interview_dd").html(d);
        })
    });
});
```